# Mostrar imagen tipo blob

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob, download

Buen dia intento descargar una imagen tipo blob desde mysql para un formulario empleados al momento de descargarla me muestra el campo vacio con el primer codigo que dejo a continuacion:

Ya tengo la imagen almacenada en mi base de datos pero no encuentro la manera correcta de mostrarla en mi formulario que les dejo a continuacion

Código 1:[image: codigo 1]

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("sql213.epizy.com","epiz_31980107","l20DHKEhYd");
    if (!$con){die ("ERROR AL CONECTAR CON LA BASE DE DATOS ".mysql_error());}
    $db = mysql_select_db("epiz_31980107_certificaciones",$con);
    if (!$db) {die ("ERROR AL SELECCIONAR DB ".mysql_error());}


 //ojo: con la sentencia sql, que es la que 
 //utilizamos para la consulta a mas de una tabla

 $sql = ("SELECT empleado.NoReloj,certificaciones.Certificacion,certificaciones.Fecha_Cert,certificaciones.Fecha_Ven 
                FROM empleado, certificaciones WHERE empleado.NoReloj='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."' AND certificaciones.empleado_id ='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");

 //realizamos la consulta
 $consulta2= ("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
$consuimg= ("SELECT Imagen FROM empleado  WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");

 $result2=mysql_query($consulta2);
$resuimg=mysql_query($consuimg);
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);


 if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){

    if($datos=mysql_fetch_row($result2)){
        $matricula2=$datos[0];
        $img=$datos[1];
        $nombre2=$datos[2];
        $apellido1=$datos[3];
        $apellido2=$datos[4];
        $fecha=$datos[5];
        $area=$datos[6];
        
        
    }
 
 }
 

 ?>

 <table align="center">
  
 <tr>
    <td>Numero de Reloj</td>
    <td>Area</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" name="matricula" value="<?php echo $matricula2; ?>" disabled></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $area; ?>" disabled></td>
 <img value="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
```

Pero al intentarlo con el codigo2 que dejo a continuacion me arrobaja la imagen como rota que no la esta pudiendo recuperar les agradeceria mucho si pudiera ayudarme a saber que estoy haciendo mal.

De antemano graicas

Código2: [image: codigo 2]

```
<?php
    
    $con = mysql_connect ("sql213.epizy.com","epiz_31980107","l20DHKEhYd");
    if (!$con){die ("ERROR AL CONECTAR CON LA BASE DE DATOS ".mysql_error());}
    $db = mysql_select_db("epiz_31980107_certificaciones",$con);
    if (!$db) {die ("ERROR AL SELECCIONAR DB ".mysql_error());}


 //ojo: con la sentencia sql, que es la que 
 //utilizamos para la consulta a mas de una tabla

 $sql = ("SELECT empleado.NoReloj,certificaciones.Certificacion,certificaciones.Fecha_Cert,certificaciones.Fecha_Ven 
                FROM empleado, certificaciones WHERE empleado.NoReloj='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."' AND certificaciones.empleado_id ='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");

 //realizamos la consulta
 $consulta2= ("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
$consuimg= ("SELECT Imagen FROM empleado  WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
 $result2=mysql_query($consulta2);
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$resimg = mysql_query($consuimg,$con);


 if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){

    if($datos=mysql_fetch_row($result2)){
        $matricula2=$datos[0];
        $nombre2=$datos[2];
        $apellido1=$datos[3];
        $apellido2=$datos[4];
        $fecha=$datos[5];
        $area=$datos[6];
        
        
    }
 } 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resimg)) {
  ?>
  <img src="data:<?php echo  base64_encode($row['Imagen']); ?>">

 

 <?php
 }

  
 ?>

 <table align="center">

 <tr>
    <td>Numero de Reloj</td>
    <td>Area</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" name="matricula" value="<?php echo $matricula2; ?>" disabled></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $area; ?>" disabled></td>
```

Comment: Para mostrar imagen tipo blob, tiene que hacer un `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagen).'"/>';`

Comment: El echo en donde lo tendria que poner disculpa dentro del if o en las secciones donde tengo los input?

Answer (score 0):

te paso como hago yo la llamada a la imagen.
Te recomiendo que mantengas identado el codigo y mas ordenado para que te facilite en el futuro hacer algun cambio.

```
<?php
    
    $con = mysql_connect ("sql213.epizy.com","epiz_31980107","l20DHKEhYd");
    if (!$con){die ("ERROR AL CONECTAR CON LA BASE DE DATOS ".mysql_error());}
    $db = mysql_select_db("epiz_31980107_certificaciones",$con);
    if (!$db) {die ("ERROR AL SELECCIONAR DB ".mysql_error());}


 //ojo: con la sentencia sql, que es la que 
 //utilizamos para la consulta a mas de una tabla

 $sql = ("SELECT empleado.NoReloj,certificaciones.Certificacion,certificaciones.Fecha_Cert,certificaciones.Fecha_Ven 
                FROM empleado, certificaciones WHERE empleado.NoReloj='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."' AND certificaciones.empleado_id ='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");

 //realizamos la consulta
 $consulta2= ("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
$consuimg= ("SELECT Imagen FROM empleado  WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
 $result2=mysql_query($consulta2);
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$resimg = mysql_query($consuimg,$con);


 if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){

    if($datos=mysql_fetch_row($result2)){
        $matricula2=$datos[0];
        $nombre2=$datos[2];
        $apellido1=$datos[3];
        $apellido2=$datos[4];
        $fecha=$datos[5];
        $area=$datos[6];
        
        
    }
 } 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resimg)) {
  ?>
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=base64_encode($row['Imagen'])?>" >

 <?php
 }

  
 ?>

 <table align="center">

 <tr>
    <td>Numero de Reloj</td>
    <td>Area</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" name="matricula" value="<?php echo $matricula2; ?>" disabled></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $area; ?>" disabled></td>
```

En el caso que la consutla te vaya a retornar una sola fila (por ejemplo si estas buscando datos de un empleado en particular) podes hacerlo asi (evitando bucles innecesarios)

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT NoReloj, Imagen FROM empleado WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'",$con);
    
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    list($noreloj,$imagen) = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    
    echo 'N. Reloj: $noreloj <br>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagen).'" >';
}
```

Fijate si la consulta te esta devolviendo datos

Comment: Buen dia
Sabes que ya lo puse como lo haces tu pero me sigue arrojando la imagen como no capturada solo me muestra la imagen rota .

Comment: No se si estoy haciendo algo mal en la consulta o en el while si esta correcto usar el assoc? o deberia usar otro?

Comment: ahi hice un cambio, revisalo